# Como saber si un procedimiento de almacenado que se ejecuta dentro de otro procedimiento , retorna un error, excepción o vacío desde C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedure

En este codigo muestro solo un (EJEMPLO) donde tengo un Procedimiento de Almacenado y dentro de este obtengo datos desde otro Procedimiento, Como puedo capturar el valor que retorna este procedimiento o los valores de salida **(sp_SearchTurn)** antes de obtener el que retorna el procedimiento Principal **(sp_Process)**.

**Es decir como acceder a los valores de salida (output) del procedimiento secundario que no se están declarados en los parámetros principales del procedimiento (sp_Process)**

Los valores output los obtengo bien y los uso dentro del procedimiento principal, pero necesito obtener esos valores output que pertenecen al procedimiento secundario en c# , para poder informar al usuario  si sucedió algo durante el proceso. (Como un Log) si no se encontró la información que busco en el procedimiento interno.

En C# he intentado agregando esos parámetros como salida, pero como no pertenecen a los parámetros del procedimiento principal al momento de ejecutar salta la excepción que el procedimiento de almacenado tiene mas argumentos de los especificados.

**NOTA: El procedimiento de almacenado funciona perfecto, solo necesito obtener esos valores de salida del procedimiento secundario en c# (NO DEBO MODIFICAR LOS PROCEDIMIENTOS DE ALMACENADO)**

Ejemplo:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Process] (
    @id numeric, 
    @type_time      char(1)
 )
As

declare     @terminal       varchar(30),
    @id_employee    numeric,
    @hour           datetime,
    @date       datetime,
    @inic           numeric

set  @terminal =   host_name()
set  @inic = convert(numeric,replace(left(right(convert(varchar(80),getdate(),9),14),12),':',''))

-- El otro procedimiento (Estos valores necesito capturarlos en c#)
exec sp_SearchTurn    @hour,
                     @turn  output ,
                     @date_valid output

print @turn

Declare @period  numeric(10)
Select  @period = period from setup
            where convert(char(10),date_valid,111)=convert(char(10),@date,111)  and id_turn = @turn 

-- El codigo del procedimiento continua esto solo es un ejemplo
-- El codigo del procedimiento continua esto solo es un ejemplo
-- El codigo del procedimiento continua esto solo es un ejemplo
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70129/discussion-on-question-by-jr0driguezv-como-saber-si-un-procedimiento-de-almacena).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de mucha investigación encontré este método y lo adaptaré para que funcione con lo que necesito.

Capturando los valores de impresión , mensajes  o output del manejador de Sql Server (de este modo crearé un Log de los mensajes y realizar la acción que deseo.)

Con el Evento: **SqlInfoMessageEventArgs**

```
 myConnection.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(myConnection_InfoMessage);

 void myConnection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs
e) { myStringBuilderDefinedAsClassVariable.AppendLine(e.Message); }
```

Créditos a : **@AdaTheDev**

**Mas información:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880471/capture-stored-procedure-print-output-in-net

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-events